# How tool to split polylines into two-part lines at vertices in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, topology, vertices, cogo

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 at and we have a problem. There is a [serious topology bug](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDgzNDA2) that I've mentioned in another question that is affecting our workflow. At present, Esri has stated the fix will be in 10.2, but my government is not able to upgrade to 10.2 so easily. Polylines flagged by topology as overlapping or not being covered by something are normally easily subtracted. With the bug, the subtraction affect the entire polyline, beyond the topologically incorrect area.

My workaround is to use the `Split Into COGO Lines` tool, which is on the COGO toolbar, to split the offending polyline at all nodes, including where the subtraction should end (checking for topology errors generates nodes). Then, when I do the subtract, it only wipes out the offending lines. However, it also adds COGO attributes to all the other segments along the former polyline. This attribute update behavior is undesirable.

Is there a simple tool that would split a line at all nodes or vertices indiscriminately--and either leave COGO attributes in place, or wipe them?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember a few split line at vertex tools in the editing or advanced editing tools. There is one that will split lines at intersection and I think that's the name of it. I'd give better guidance but I'm not at my desk to see the tools in front of me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what this tool will do to COGO attributes but, if you have an Advanced license, then the **[Split Line At Vertices](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Split_Line_At_Vertices/00170000003z000000/)** tool from Data Management may be what you should try.

Comment: This looks promising! I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Ah, so this tool splits the features alright, but it requires a different output dataset. I need to split the live data.

Answer (score 1):

In the editor toolbar there is a tool called split line.  You must click within the snapping tolerance, but this should allow you to do what you need to do. It will break the feature into two parts and than you can delete the portion you no longer want.